# Pass datas to another component in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, axios

I have this filter function (belongs a List component), then I need to pass **the results to another component**, (they are sibling) to fill my DataTable (parent component):

```
async filtroVariaveis () {
                try {
                    this.loading = true;

                    this.variaveis = await this.variaveisService.listVariables();

                    let idGrupos = null;
                    if (!this.grupos[0] && this.maquinaSelecionada[0]) {
                        idGrupos = this.gruposOpcoes.map(m => m.id);
                    }

                    if (!this.grupos[0] && !this.maquinaSelecionada[0] && this.areaSelecionada[0]) {
                        const idMaquinas = this.maquinasOpcoes.map(m => m.id);
                        const grupo = this.gruposOpcoes.filter(a => idMaquinas.includes(a.id_maquina));

                        idGrupos = grupo.map(a => a.id);
                    }

                    if (this.grupos[0]) {
                        idGrupos = this.grupos.map(g => g.id);
                    }

                    const tipos = this.tipoVariavel.map(t => t === "Analógica" ? t = "ANALOGICA" : "DIGITAL");
                    const tag = this.tagInput || this.variaveis.map(t => t.tag);
                    const descricao = this.descricaoInput || this.variaveis.map(d => d.descricao);

                    this.filtroAplicado = ((await this.variaveisService.listVariables(idGrupos, tipos, tag, descricao)) || []);
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
```

this.variaveisService is my Axios services that communicates with my API.

My List component:

```
<template>
<two-cards>
        <template #header>
            <h4 class="card-title">Filtros</h4>
            <slot>
                <router-link
                    to="/variaveis/add"
                    class="btn btn-success text-white align-self-center"
                >
                Adicionar variável
                </router-link>
            </slot>
        </template>
        <template #one>
            <form class="mt-2" @submit.prevent="filtroVariaveis">
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col form-group col-sm-6">
                        <label for="data-final">Tag: </label>
                        <b-form-input
                            v-model="tagInput"
                            id="data-final"
                            input-class="bg-white"
                        ></b-form-input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col form-group col-sm-6">
                        <label for="data-inicial">Descrição: </label>
                        <b-form-input
                            v-model="descricaoInput"
                            id="data-inicial"
                            input-class="bg-white"
                        ></b-form-input>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                        <label class="mt-2">Área </label>
                            <vue-multi-select
                                class="multi-100"
                                v-model="areaSelecionada"
                                @input="checarArea"
                                search
                                historyButton
                                :options="{ multi: false, labelName: 'nome' }"
                                :selectOptions="areasOpcoes"
                                :btnLabel="() => areaSelecionada[0] ? areaSelecionada[0].nome : 'Selecione'"
                            />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                        <label class="mt-2">Máquina </label>
                            <vue-multi-select
                                class="multi-100"
                                v-model="maquinaSelecionada"
                                :disabled="!areaSelecionada[0]"
                                @input="checarMaquina"
                                search
                                historyButton
                                :options="{ multi: true, labelName: 'nome' }"
                                :selectOptions="maquinasOpcoes"
                                :btnLabel="() => customLabel(maquinaSelecionada)"
                            />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                        <label class="mt-2">Grupo </label>
                            <vue-multi-select
                                class="multi-100"
                                v-model="grupos"
                                search
                                historyButton
                                :options="{ multi: true }"
                                :selectOptions="gruposOpcoes"
                                :btnLabel="() => customLabel(grupos)"
                            />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                        <label class="mt-2">Tipo</label>
                            <vue-multi-select
                                class="multi-100"
                                v-model="tipoVariavel"
                                search
                                historyButton
                                :options="{ multi: true }"
                                :selectOptions="tiposOpcoes"
                                :btnLabel="() => customLabel(tipoVariavel)"
                            />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-end tcs-card-footer-action">
                    <button
                        class="btn btn-success tcs-btn"
                        type="search"
                    >
                        <SearchIcon />
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </template>
        <template #two>
            <GenericList
                title="variáveis"
                :linhas="linhas"
                data-table-state-name="Variável"
                add-route="add_variavel"
                edit-route="edit_variavel"
                :cols="['#', 'Tag', 'Descrição', 'Tipo']"
                :cols-name="['id', 'tag', 'descricao', 'tipo']"
                :cols-map="i => [i.id, i.tag, i.descricao, i.tipo]"
            />
        </template>
    </two-cards>
</template>

computed: {
            linhas () {
                return this.lista.map((row) => ({
                    href: { name: this.editRoute, params: { id: row.id }},
                    cols: this.colsMap(row)
                }));
            }
        },
```

My GenericList component, where I need to put this datas:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <DataTable
            scroll
            :async="pagination"
            :loading="loading"
            :colunas="parsedCols"
            :linhas="linhas"
            :errMsg="errMsg"
            :state="dataTableState"
            @state-change="setStateDataTable"
        >
            <template #results-page v-if="pagination">
                <select
                    class="custom-select ml-1"
                    :value="results"
                    @input="changeResults"
                    data-cy="resultados-pagina"
                >
                    <option value="10">10 por página</option>
                    <option value="20">20 por página</option>
                    <option value="50">50 por página</option>
                    <option value="100">100 por página</option>
                    <option v-if="canShowAllResults" value="-1">
                        Mostrar todos
                    </option>
                </select>
            </template>
            <template v-for="col in cols" v-slot:[col]="{ value, item }">
                <slot :name="col" :value="value" :item="item">
                    <router-link
                        v-if="value && value.rota && value.nome && value.id"
                        :to="{ name: value.rota, params: { id: value.id } }"
                        title="Ir para a edição"
                        >
                        <edit-icon size="16" /> {{ value.nome }}</router-link
                    >
                </slot>
            </template>
        </DataTable>
        <Paginator
            :page="page"
            :pages="pages"
            :count="count"
            :disabled="loading"
            :first="first"
            :last="last"
            @paginate="paginate"
        />
    </div>
</template>

props: {
        loading: Boolean,

        title: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },

        addRoute: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },

        editRoute: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },

        dataTableStateName: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },

        lista: {
            type: Array
        },

        linhas: {
            type: Array
        },

        cols: {
            type: Array,
            required: true
        },

        colsMap: {
            type: Function,
            required: true
        },

        colsName: {
            type: Array,
            required: true
        },

        canShowAllResults: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        },

        showInativos: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        }
    },

data () {
    return {
        errMsg: "",

        pagination: false,
        page: 0,
        pages: 1,
        results: 20,
        first: 0,
        last: 0,
        count: 0
    };
},

computed: {
    dataTableState () {
        return this.$store.state.dataTables[
            "dataTable" + this.dataTableStateName
        ];
    },

    parsedCols () {
        return this.cols.map((c, idx) => this.colsName[idx] ? c : { value: c, sortable: false }
        );
    }
},
```

I dont know how to fill this DataTable, someone can helps me?

Comment: Depends on the position of the 2 components. are the components sibling ? or parent to child?

Comment: @ElsaKarami They are sibling..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `$emit` and `$on` for passing data between sibling components.
please look at this example

when you pass data into another component you have to set this line:

```
this.$root.$emit('eventing', data);
```

and after that, you can receive data into the destination component like this example:

1)

```
mounted() {
  this.$root.$on('eventing',this.functionName);
}
```

OR

2)

```
mounted() {
    this.$root.$on('eventing', data => {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

please pay attention, you had better set `$off` into the destination component

1)

```
 beforeDestroy() {
    this.$root.$off("eventing", this.functionName);
  }
```

OR

2)

```
beforeDestroy() {
  this.$root.$off("eventing");
}
```

you can find data you need into arguments in the `this.functionName`

Comment: Where I put `this.$root.$emit('eventing', data);`?

Comment: when you need to pass data into second component. for example, I need to pass data when I click btn into the first component

Comment: when you need the data into the second component?

Comment: I need when I click to do the search, this result is what will fill my table. I'm a beginner so I don't really know what to do.. I understand your example I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: So I would like how I could do this, with real examples according to what was shown in the question

Comment: it's ok. I can help you. you need to set '$emit' inside response API after search. do you call API after click?

Comment: Yes, I call in here: `this.filtroAplicado = ((await this.variaveisService.listVariables(idGrupos, tipos, tag, descricao)) || [])` in my List component, inside the filter function. Passing my datas

Comment: Do you want my DataTable component to? Maybe can be useful

Comment: what is the btn :    ` <button
                        class="btn btn-success tcs-btn"
                        type="search"
                    >
                        <SearchIcon />
                    </button>`

Comment: you need to set $emit inside this.variaveisService response

Comment: `<button class =" btn btn-success tcs-btn "type =" search "> <SearchIcon /> </button>` Is a search icon for the user click

Comment: why you don't have @click="searching" in this btn?

Comment: Like this? this.filtroAplicado = ((await this.variaveisService.listVariables(idGrupos, tipos, tag, descricao), this.$root.$emit()) || []);

Comment: I have the `@submit.prevent="filtroVariaveis`

Comment: no . can i see this function this.variaveisService.listVariables?  you call this service here . i wanna see inside this.variaveisService.listVariables service

Comment: `async listVariables (idGrupos, tipos, tag, descricao) {
  const response = await this.axios.get("variables", {
   params: {
    id_grupos: (idGrupos || []).join(","),
    tipos: (tipos || []).join(","),
    tag,
    descricao
   }
  });
  return response.data;
 }`

Comment: I opine you can set $emit  before `return response.data`

Comment: This service is used in other parts of the project, wouldn't that cause problems?

Comment: `this.filtroAplicado = ((await this.variaveisService.listVariables(idGrupos, tipos, tag, descricao)) || []);`

`if (this.filtroAplicado && this.filtroAplicado.length){
this.$root.$emit ....
}`

Comment: $emit(what)? And what I do in GenericList to listen that?

Comment: this.$root.$emit('eventing', data); 
and inside GenericList page , you need to set $on like : 

`mounted() {
    this.$root.$on('eventing', data => {
        console.log(data);
    });
}`

Comment: This seems to work, thanks Elsa! The console is already showing me what I want, but I still don't know how to fill the table with this results, if you can help me with that I really really appreciate...

Comment: I accept your answer anyway! :)

Comment: thank you. you need to set v-if inside table tag. because the table render before call emit

Comment: `beforeDestroy() {
  this.$root.$off("eventing");
}` You mentioned it, how do I use it?

Comment: can i see `this.$root.$on` code you used it?

Comment: In my Generic List component:   `mounted () {
   this.$root.$on("filtroVariaveis", data => {
    this.pagination = true;

    console.log(data);
   });
  }`

Comment: you can set like this:


 beforeDestroy() {
    this.$root.$off("filtroVariaveis");
  }

after mounted part

Comment: Thanks again :) Last question, "to set v-if inside table tag" thats inside GenericList too, right? But I already have `v-if="pagination"` so I have to do something inside this?

Comment: your welcome. you can define variable for fill with data inside $on like this:
`mounted () {    
this.$root.$on("filtroVariaveis", data => {     
this.pagination = true;      
this.searchResult = data   
}); }`


and you can improve your v-if like this:  `v-if="pagination && searchResult"`

Comment: Hi again Elsa! I still haven't been able to fill the DataTable, can you help me? I opened a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69712392/datable-in-vuejs-is-not-filled